# Pyyaml: Default dump behavior for inherited classes

Tags: python, inheritance, yaml, pyyaml

I have a class that inherits from one of the built-ins:

```py
from yaml import YAMLObject, dump
class D(dict, YAMLObject):
   yaml_tag = u'!!map'
   ...
```

Is there a way to tell pyyaml that the dump of any instance of `D` should be treated like the parent (in this case dict)? I.e., I would like the following output:

```py
d = {'a':1}
print( dump(d) )
>>> a: 1
```

Instead of

```
print( dump(D(d)) )
>>> !%21map {}
```

As you can see I already tried assigning the class a default tag, but that did not quite work out.
Defining a custom dumper is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: Why is a custom dumper not an option? That's really the correct solution here. If we understand your limitations we might be able to offer better suggestions. You could just dump it using `json` instead, which (a) seems to handle things that inherit from `dict` without any further work, and (b) JSON is valid YAML, so you're done.

Comment: @larsks Because the remaining bit of the project I am working on is using the default Dumper and there is no way for me to modify that part of the code. I thought such use cases could be handled from within the class itself -- seemed like a logical place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a custom `to_yaml` method in your `D` class:

```
import yaml


class D(dict, yaml.YAMLObject):
    yaml_tag = "!map"

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, dumper, data):
        return dumper.represent_dict(dict(data))


d = D({"foo": "bar"})
print(yaml.dump(d))
```

The output of the above is:

```
foo: bar
```

Note that this only works with `yaml.dump` and not with `yaml.safe_dump`. The value of `yaml_tag` seems to be irrelevant, but it must be set; without setting it, the output of the above would be:

```
!!python/object/new:__main__.D
dictitems:
  foo: bar
```

Comment: Thank you, this works nicely. Still, I wonder why the tag behaviour is the way it is. I'd expect the default yaml_tag to be picked up and understood

Answer (score 0):

Short addition: Converting the data back to a `dict` first before dumping it is another elegant solution I completely missed:

```py
d = D({'a':1})
print( dump(dict(d)) )
>>> a: 1
```